# Class parameters from enum

Tags: swift, struct, enums

I've got a question on how to use enums and classes together.

Consider the following:

```
enum parameter {
    case agility
    case strength
    case mind
}

struct heroParameters {
    let maxInitialParam: UInt32! = 10

    var agility: UInt32!
    var strength: UInt32!
    var mind: UInt32!

    init() {
        self.agility = arc4random_uniform(self.maxInitialParam)
        self.strength = arc4random_uniform(self.maxInitialParam)
        self.mind = arc4random_uniform(self.maxInitialParam)
    }
}

class Hero {
    var parameters: heroParameters!

    required init() {
         self.parameters = heroParameters()
    }

    func setParameter(parameterName: parameter, _ value: UInt32) {
         // ?
    }
}
```

The question I have is: is there a way to properly set up a list of struct variables from enum above in case there will be a need to modify a list of parameters?

In general, is there a way to init a struct consisting of unknown amount of variables all listed in separate enum?

Either way, I might be thinking in a completely wrong way and I need to understand how to work with these properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to store the parameters in `HeroParameters`.  If you make your enum `Parameter` have a rawValue type of `Int`, then `HeroParameters` will be able to create default values for all of them without knowing ahead of time how many there are.

This works because `Parameter(rawValue:)` will return `nil` once the `rawValue` reaches the maximum number of enums, and the `while` loop will end.

```
enum Parameter: Int {
    case agility
    case strength
    case mind
}

struct HeroParameters {
    let maxInitialParam: UInt32 = 10

    var parameters = [Parameter: UInt32]()

    init() {
        var rawValue = 0
        while let parameter = Parameter(rawValue: rawValue) {
             parameters[parameter] = arc4random_uniform(maxInitialParam)
             rawValue += 1
        }
    }
}

class Hero {
    var parameters = HeroParameters()

    func setParameter(parameterName: Parameter, _ value: UInt32) {
        parameters.parameters[parameterName] = value
    }
}
```

---

Following @vadian's excellent suggestion in the comments, you can define your `Hero` class with the ability to set/get parameters using subscripts:

```
class Hero {
    var parameters = HeroParameters()

    subscript(key: Parameter) -> UInt32 {
        get { return parameters.parameters[key]! }
        set { parameters.parameters[key] = newValue}
    }
}
```

Then, you have a nice clean solution:

```
let hero = Hero()

hero[.agility] = 3
hero[.strength] = 7

print(hero[.strength])  // "7"
```

Comment: Wow, this is much better than my solution :-)

Comment: PS: I'd suggest to add enum subscription in `Hero` for convenience `subscript(key: Parameter) -> UInt32 { get { return parameters.parameters[key]! }  set { parameters.parameters[key] = newValue }}` and get rid of the `setParameter` function

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You can't do that directly.

A workaround is to declare a dictionary in `HeroParameters` and use enum subscription.

```
enum Parameter : String {
  case Agility = "agility"
  case Strength = "strength"
  case Mind = "mind"

  static let allValues = [Agility, Strength, Mind]
}

struct HeroParameters {
  let maxInitialParam: UInt32 = 10

  var parameters = [String:UInt32]()

  subscript(key: Parameter) -> UInt32 {
    get { return parameters[key.rawValue]! }
    set { parameters[key.rawValue] = newValue }
  }

  init() {
    for aValue in Parameter.allValues {
      self[aValue] = arc4random_uniform(maxInitialParam)
    }
  }
}

class Hero {
  var parameters: HeroParameters

  required init() {
    self.parameters = HeroParameters()
  }

  func setParameter(parameterName: Parameter, _ value: UInt32) {
    parameters[parameterName] = value
  }

  func parameterForKey(key: Parameter) -> UInt32 {
     return parameters[key]
  }
}


let hero = Hero()
let strength = hero.parameterForKey(.Strength)
hero.setParameter(.Strength, 8)

let agility = hero.parameterForKey(.Agility)
let newStrength = hero.parameterForKey(.Strength)
```

All variables are declared as non-optionals and since the number of enum cases and the values are well-known at design time, all forced unwrapped values are absolutely safe.

---

Edit:

Based on vacawama's answer and Sulthan's suggestion this is an array based version

```
enum Parameter: Int {
  case Agility, Strength, Mind
}

struct HeroParameters {
  let maxInitialParam: UInt32 = 10

  var parameters = [UInt32]()

  init() {
    var rawValue = 0
    while Parameter(rawValue: rawValue) != nil {
      parameters.append(arc4random_uniform(maxInitialParam))
      rawValue += 1
    }
  }
}

class Hero {
  var parameters = HeroParameters()

  subscript(key: Parameter) -> UInt32 {
    get { return parameters.parameters[key.rawValue] }
    set { parameters.parameters[key.rawValue] = newValue }
  }
}


let hero = Hero()
hero[.Strength] = 8

let agility = hero[.Agility]
let newStrength = hero[.Strength]
```

Comment: Also note that if you make `Parameter` to inherit from `Int`, you can use an array instead of a dictionary. Since the structure is abstracted, both implementation will work the same though.

Comment: @Sulthan That's a great suggestion, too.